# WEPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem is causing the specified UIBarButtonItem to disappear

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

I've started using [WEPopoverController](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) to display some controls after clicking a UIBarButtonItem in a toolbar at the bottom of my screen. The popover displays fine, and the controls inside the popover work, however as soon as the popover is displayed the UIBarButtonItem it was anchored to disappears!

Here's the code for displaying, it's pretty straightforward:

```
WEPopoverController *wePopover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:audioController];
[wePopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 150)];
[wePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:voiceButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

It will work if I use presentPopoverFromRect, but that's not the ideal solution.

Anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am getting the same issue here. Also, the arrowhead is never pointing to the button correctly.

Comment: I don't think we ever did. I ended up just using presentPopoverFromRect: but we have since changed our layout and no longer use the popover. Good luck.

Comment: I have this bug as well, here is this issue on Github: https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the category class `UIBarButtonItem(WEPopover)` , which implements
`- (CGRect)frameInView:(UIView *)v`. 
Somewhere along the way , the custom view is nilled , and not returned to the view hierarchy afterwards.
If you try using a standard barButtonItem (no custom view) then the popover will display correctly, without hiding the item(but that's not a solution).
Anyway, presenting from rect was the solution I used as well.